# API key Authentication with spring security in spring data rest api

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data-rest

Am using spring-data-rest for developing my API and I have to use spring security to authenticate a request. When I pass a authentication details, I have to generate an API+secret key and store it in client side and sent with all further requests from that subject. And have to check it in every request and if they logout I have to regenerate key when they login again. I have implemented security as like this,

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{


    @Override protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("test").password("test").roles("test");
    }

    @Override protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("test")
            .anyRequest().anonymous()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable();
    }

}
```

and registered filter via java config.

and I have look at this [tutorial](http://www.objectpartners.com/2011/06/16/implementing-rest-authentication/) which is exactly the same am looking for. I am not good with spring and so I need to know whether am moving correctly.

Am going to implement facebook login and no registration in my site, everyone will login with facebook to access site or my app. So i wont have password too. Guide me in a proper way that how I could progress to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Facebook uses OAuth and Spring Security has a modules to handle OAuth, SAML etc.

Comment: JWT woulld be the best solution for this https://github.com/szerhusenBC/jwt-spring-security-demo

Comment: It's too bad his example was solved by telling him to do something else. I have a valid use case for this...